# Getting Set difference in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I have two sets:

```
set_A = ([('6',90), ('4',315), ('2', 135)])
```

and

```
set_B = (['A',90), ('B', 135), ('D', 240)])
```

I'm looking for a way to get the difference between the two without taking into account the single numbers and the single uppercase letters.

Output expected:  `([('4',315)])`

Both of these iterations gives me: `(['A',90), ('B', 135), ('D', 240)])`

```
different = [item for item in set_B if item not in set_A]

different = set_B.difference(set_A)
```

I need to keep track of the uppercase letters, and of the single numbers. I don't have any idea of how to do this.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you are saying if the 2nd item in the tuple appears in both (or just the 2nd set), then that item shouldn't show up in your "difference"?

Comment: Exactly @jeffcarey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after, if not please clarify your reqs:

```
diff = set(a_item for a_item in set_A if a_item[1] not in [b_item[1] for b_item in set_B])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert them to dictionaries because `set.difference` on the dictionary keys is really cheap:

```
>>> # Inverted dictionaries because you want to match the second element
>>> dict_A = {key: value for value, key in set_A}
>>> dict_B = {key: value for value, key in set_B}

>>> [(dict_A[key], key) for key in set(dict_A).difference(dict_B)]
[('4', 315)]
```

The last step does the difference that you wanted but it also converts it back to a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right, assuming we only need to check duplication on the second element of each tuple, you can simply do :

**For Set A - Set B**

```
different = [item for item in set_A if item[1] not in zip(*set_B)[1]]
different
[('4', 315)]
```

**For Set B - Set A**

```
different = [item for item in set_B if item[1] not in zip(*set_A)[1]]
different
[('D', 240)]
```

Hope this helps!